# Как сделать прозрачный фон у изображения

Tags: php, png

Предположим у нас есть какой-то логотип (`node.png`), который нужно наложить на другое изображение (`sea.jpg`). Но вот беда, логотип с белым фоном, а хочется прозрачного. Погуглил, но ничего толкового не нашел (вернее нашел, но из-за собственной криворукости ничего не получилось). Сейчас имеется вот такой код, но что-то не работает:

```
<?php
    $src_img = imagecreatefrompng('node.png');
    imagecolortransparent($src_img, 0xffffff);
    $dst_img = imagecreatefromjpeg('sea.jpg');
    imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 900, 500, 25, 100, 70, 160, 300, 200);
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    imagejpeg($dst_img);
?>
```

Господа хэшкодовцы, можете что-нибудь дельное посоветовать по данному вопросу?

Comment: Если node.png сам по себе имеет белый фон, то не получится. Сделайте фон прозрачным, например, в фотошопе и тогда всё получится. PNG поддерживает прозрачность, но при этом она должна там быть.

Comment: @spirit, да, действительно, теперь все работает, а я мучился, спасибо!

Comment: хотел с Вами разобраться, но раз уже помогло, то перемещу в ответ=)

Comment: @andreyqin может так? (Координаты и размеры изменены под мои картинки)

    <?php
        $src_img = imagecreatefrompng('node.png');
        imagecolortransparent($src_img, 0xffffff);
        $dst_img = imagecreatefromjpeg('sea.jpg');
        imagecopymerge($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, 100);
        header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
        imagejpeg($dst_img);
     ?>

заменено imagecopyresampled на imagecopymerge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если node.png сам по себе имеет белый фон, то не получится. Сделайте фон прозрачным, например, в фотошопе и тогда всё получится. PNG поддерживает прозрачность, но при этом она должна там быть.